# How to define member function coming from non-template base class

Tags: c++, templates, abstract

I have a non-templated abstract base class. How do I define the pure virtual function outside derived class?

```
    #include <iostream>

    class base {
         public:
         virtual void func() = 0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    class der : public base{
    };

    template<typename T>
    void der<T>::func()
    {
         std::cout<<"In Der";
    }
```

The following error comes up:

```
template.cpp:13: error: no ‘void der<T>::func()’ member function declared in class ‘der<T>’
template.cpp:13: error: template definition of non-template ‘void der<T>::func()’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare the member function.

```
template<typename T>
    class der : public base{
    public:
        void func();
    };
```

There's no automatic declaration of member functions that you may or may not wish to override in a derived class - you have to explicitly declare and define these. Whether the derived class is implemented as a template or not doesn't matter for this.

Answer (score 2):

You must declare the virtual override in the derived class definition.

```
template <typename T>
class der : public base {
public:
    virtual void func();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
#include <iostream>

class base {
     public:
     virtual void func() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class der : public base{
  public:
  void func()
  {
       std::cout<<"In Der";
  }
};
```

It has been recommended to me to drop function definitions straight into templates when possible, except for specializations.

*edit:* 'inline' was not the best choice of word here

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure any longer, to be honest. Browsing through some references I don't see it spelled out clearly anywhere. I think the idea was that since they should be in the same header anyway unless you have 'export' in your compiler, you'd just get shorter code through avoiding template<...> and so on.